# Using public runners for self-hosted gitlab instance

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have following image configuration in my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
default:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest
  #image: curlimages/curl:latest
...
```

this works fine when I am deploying on  `https://gitlab.com/`, however when you try to deploy my code along with above ci configuration I get following errors in my CICD:

```
This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it.
Go to project CI settings
```

My question is while using  `https://gitlab.com/` I didn't specifically assigned any runners to my project through settings. But now it seems I have supposed to do that.

- Why is that?
- And if this is necessary how can I do this?

Comment: You are using the shared runner provided by GitLab.com (refers to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/gitlab_com/index.html#ci-pipeline-minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using gitlab.com -- the gitlab instance has shared runners configured available to run all untagged CI jobs.

On your own self-hosted gitlab you must either configure your own shared runners for your instance or register runners to your projects/groups.

You cannot use the gitlab.com shared runners on a self-hosted gitlab instance.

From [scope of runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/runners_scope.html):

> **Shared Runners**
>
> Shared runners are available to every project in a GitLab instance.
>
> Use shared runners when you have multiple jobs with similar requirements. Rather than having multiple runners idling for many projects, you can have a few runners that handle multiple projects.
>
> **If you are using a self-managed instance of GitLab:**
>
> Your administrator can install and register shared runners by going to your project’s Settings > CI/CD, expanding the Runners section, and clicking Show runner installation instructions. These instructions are also available in the documentation.
> The administrator can also configure a maximum number of shared runner pipeline minutes for each group.
>
> **If you are using GitLab.com:**
>
> You can select from a list of shared runners that GitLab maintains.
> The shared runners consume the pipelines minutes included with your account.

I suppose you *technically* would be able to use public GitLab runners for your self-hosted instance if you create an account on gitlab.com and [setup CICD for external repos](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/) pointing to your self-hosted instance -- but your minutes would be a separate entitlement from your self-hosted license, among other serious limitations.